# Turning read-only off in flash drive

Tags: usb-drive, read-only

I can't format my 4Gb flash drive. Every time I try to open it, this error appears:
[image: that error]

Gparted couldn't do anything too because of protection. I also tried `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc1` and `dosfsck /dev/sdc1` in vain. Everything was fine until I took it off while copying data.  How can I manage to format it?

Comment: Does your  USB have a little switch on it? This will be a write protection switch.

Comment: no, it doesn't, I checked